# LWC as Quick Action on Case Object is not showing

Tags: lightning-web-components, chatter, quickaction

I have created Action as LWC and my xml tragets are

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
          <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
      </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Feed tracking is enabled and chatter tab is also there but My action is not showing either in chatter tab or on top but if I disable feed tracking then it is showing in top.
I want it to show in either chatter tab or on top with feed tracking enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_web_component_actions_create.htm&type=5), You can add a Lightning web component action to the Highlights Panel of a case record page if you add it as a dynamic action in Lightning App Builder. You can't use the page layout to add a Lightning web component action to the Highlights Panel of a case record.

### Observation

1. Aura component action will appear in chatter component when feed tracking is enabled and in highlight panel when feed tracking is disabled or dynamic action is enabled
2. LWC Component action will not appear either on chatter component or highlight panel unless dynamic action is enabled or feed tracking is disabled.

so, if you want to have LWC component quick action to appear in chatter component without enabling the dynamic action, you should wrap it in Aura and use it as Aura component quick action.