# Put an Aura component in the Chatter Publisher

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, chatter, quickaction, publisher-action

I am trying to build an aura component to send an OTP to clients but I can't figure out how to put it in the Chatter Publisher, I was going to code a LWC but I understood from [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383723/lwc-as-quick-action-on-case-object-is-not-showing/383746#383746) that I can't use a LWC directly but that I would need to put it in a Aura component.
I am struggling to find a way to put it there but I can't seem to find a way, I can not put it anywhere else on the page because the page is highly custom and I can't affort to make it too long by adding a new component that is not inside the chatter Publisher.